# After changing httpd-xampp file to read allow for 127.0.0.1 I was forbidden access to phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Running a website using XAMPP and setting up security for phpmyadmin and mySQL when I added the following authorization for access to phpmyadmin:

Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/XAMP/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "D:/XAMP/phpMyAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1

But now my own machine can't connect to phpmyadmin and I receive Forbidden message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because that the Apache version your localhost running is updated and the Apache configuration your using might be outdated.

> Earlier as in your configuration, the access control based on client
> host name, IP address, and other characteristics of client requests
> was done using the directives Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy.
>
> But now, such access control is done in the same way as other
> authorization checks, using the new module [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html). The
> old access control idioms should be replaced by the new authentication
> mechanisms, although for compatibility with old configurations, the
> new module [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html) is provided.

**Replace**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

**With**

```
Require local
```

> The local provider allows access to the server if any of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The client address matches 127.0.0.0/8
> - The client address is ::1
> - Both the client and the server address of the connection are the same

Comment: Actually, now that I have require local I can access phpmyadmin from other netwroks as well